# How much do BitTorrent and WebTorrent have in common?

Tags: p2p, specifications, bittorrent, file-sharing, webtorrent

I recently heard about WebTorrent and decided to try one of those audio player javascript demos to see if I could make it play a random MP3 from BitTorrent network.
 It didn't work and I contacted the author to find out that those are "[two separate networks](https://github.com/enorrmann/youshark/issues/3#issuecomment-248621911)". 
 
 This made me wonder - how much do those two networks have in common?
  For example, do they use the same .torrent file specification and one file can be found both under WebTorrent and BitTorrent under the same InfoHash?
 
 Are there any torrent discovery websites like ThePirateBay for WebTorrent that I could use to see what's already there?

Answer (score 4):

WebTorrent is based in BitTorrent, they follow the same torrent file spec.

WebTorrent [in the browser](https://github.com/feross/webtorrent#in-the-browser) can only connect to WebRTC peers, WebTorrent [in NodeJS](https://github.com/feross/webtorrent#in-nodejs) can only connect to TCP/UDP peers. [WebTorrent Hybrid](https://github.com/feross/webtorrent-hybrid) (NodeJS) client can connect to both using a headless electron process. [WebTorrent Desktop](https://webtorrent.io/desktop/) is a desktop app that can connect to both networks.

You might be interested in reading the [FAQ](https://github.com/feross/webtorrent/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-does-webtorrent-work)

There's no website for WebRTC-network torrents discovery, yet.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any resources I could use to estimate the size of the network and whether any popular torrents are already there?

Comment: @d33tah There's no website for such functionality yet. The stats are these: https://tracker.btorrent.xyz/stats

Comment: Thanks again! Do you know of any tracker that serves full_scrape data like this in here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39822400/1091116

Comment: @d33tah Wouldn't know. Sorry.