# How does ThePirateBay know the number of seeders for its torrents?

Tags: bittorrent, dht

How do websites like ThePirateBay.org work? I heard that the age of trackers is pretty much over, so I guess they extract data from DHT. I wrote a simple DHT scraper, but it was pretty slow to query the servers - does TPB have its own DHT nodes they sniff on? Do they verify whether the peers actually have data?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about how someone might be using a certain tool or technology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not staff on TPB (or any other torrent index site) and have no exact information how they do it, but my best guess is that they regulary fetch a `full scrape` from the (working) trackers that are provided in the magnet links on the site.

Currently those are:
udp://tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969
udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969

Looking at the trackers homepages:
http://tracker.leechers-paradise.org
http://coppersurfer.tk

Both have links to download a `full scrape`:
http://scrape.leechers-paradise.org/static_scrape
http://coppersurfer.tk/full_scrape_not_a_tracker.tar.gz

While it's possible to scrape the DHT, it takes large resources to do (as you have noticed), so I find it very unlikely that they do that.

Disclaimer: Those trackers don't have any (pirated) file content, are not bittorrent sites and don't have any torrent files.

Comment: How would one go about parsing the scraped data? All I got was a blob file I'm not too sure what do do with.